# Finding the Distribution of a sample

Tags: r, probability

Hello everyone I’m a beginner and I am having issues setting up this problem. Let's say you toss two coins. Let x be the resulting number of heads and y be the number of tails. I need to find the distribution in R. Here is what I have attempted:

```
Sample(0:2, x,y, size=10), prob=1/4, replace=true)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! `?sample` will show the syntax and options for drawing a sample in R. Searching Stack Overflow will turn up a number of previously answered questions both on how to identify a distribution and how to test if a sample deviates from a distribution you assume it to have. Please see also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: What do you mean by "find the distribution"? Count the number of heads and tails? Something else?

Comment: Suggest you review the `sample` function documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sample  It clearly explains the function and it's parameters and demonstrates some examples.  Always a good idea to web search first before posting to stack overflow.

Comment: The problem as stated can be solved algebraically, so it is not clear what the programming problem that needs to be solved actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sample` function to generate random samples as suggested by the comments.

Your experiment is to toss 2 coins, but you didn't specify the number of times. Let's start with ten, as your attempted code suggests.

The `sample` function has a `prob` argument to specify the probabilities. The number of heads obtained from tossing 2 coins can be either 0, 1, or 2 (as your code correctly specifies) and these frequencies will occur with probabilities 1/4, 1/2, and 1/4, respectively. So, the R command would be:

```
n.heads <- sample(0:2, size=10, replace=TRUE, prob=c(1/4, 1/2, 1/4)); n.heads
[1] 0 1 1 1 2 1 1 0 2 1
```

And you can visualise this using a barplot:

```
barplot(table(n.heads)/10)
```

For illustration purposes, it is good practice to set the random number seed so others can follow.

```
set.seed(1)
n.heads <- sample(0:2, size=10, replace=TRUE, prob=c(1/4, 1/2, 1/4)); n.heads
[1] 1 1 2 0 1 0 0 2 2 1
barplot(table(n.heads)/10)
```

[image]

You may like to increase the size argument to see how the distribution changes. The number of tails should be similar (by symmetry).